# Would putting an expensive query on a background thread help site performance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, memcached

we are a Ruby on rails app running on Heroku, and we are using Heroku's Postgres solution for our DB.

We have a very expensive DB query. It takes approximately 45 seconds. We use memcache to cache this query ... but the first time someone goes to the page that runs this query after 24 hours in the cache, the site basically goes down as this query is running.

We are contemplating putting the query on a background thread. Would that work nicely with memcache and would that help the site performance? Would the fact that the DB is still working on a big query affect other pages loading?

Comment: Depends on why the "site basically goes down". Is this big query causing lock contention? Starving other processes for I/O? Spilling to huge tempfiles and causing serious disk churn? You need to start by working out where the system is bottlenecked and what's slowing the other queries down. Look at `pg_locks` and see http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring . Use vmstat, top, etc (if you can on Heroku) to observe the system's load. Look in `pg_stat_activity` to see whether there are lots of queries queued up and if so, what state they're in.

Answer (score 1):

It may help if the problem is not resource-intensive on the dyno or locking the database.

If neither of the cases are true, you can simply return something (a previous version, maybe start the process before the cache is stale) to the initiating client and spin a new thread.

If the intensity is on the dyno and not the database, you can try spinning up a worker dyno or a [scheduled job](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler).

If your database is locked, then you are back to the drawing board.

Oh, and if your application uses only one database connection, be sure to open another one for the thread (a dyno will take care of itself).